# littler doesn't see installed package

Tags: r, littler

I'm having a problem getting [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler) to see an installed packaged. I've gotten it down to just trying to fun this one line saved in a file called `min.R`

```
require(jsonlite)
```

I can execute this line of code and load the package just fine running the R terminal, but if I try this from the command line I get an error that `jsonlite` is not found:

```
root# r min.R
Loading required package: jsonlite
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘jsonlite’
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Additional details:

If I try `require(zoo)` this works fine when run from littler. Here is some of the output of `installed.packages()` in relevant part:

```
           Enhances
jsonlite   NA
...
zoo        NA

           License                       License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use
jsonlite   "MIT + file LICENSE"          NA              NA
...
zoo        "GPL-2 | GPL-3"               NA              NA
           OS_type MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built
jsonlite   NA      NA     "yes"            "3.0.2"
...
zoo        NA      NA     "yes"            "3.0.2"
```

Comment: Off topic, there was nothing wrong with your Meta question a minute ago about Meetups, I don't know who the idiots were who downvoted it. There's e.g. http://www.meetup.com/de/Stack-Overflow-Meetups/ and [this massive 2012 event](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/).  If you undelete it I'd be happy to write an answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'd be happy to undelete if you want to write an answer, but I can't refind the page. Have you still got the link?

Comment: Yup! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303709/in-person-meetups

Comment: Was jsonlite stored in the same place as your other packages?

Comment: @Dason thanks for fixing the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I missed this when it was originally posted.

In the past littler read nothing. I then added `/etc/littler.r` and `~/.littler.r` support.  The next version will read `/etc/R/Rprofile.site` and `~/.Rprofile` as well.

So for now just put some code into `~/.littler.r`.   As for not finding things, check via

```
$ r -e 'print(.libPaths())'
```

Comment: Thanks for this intel. I'll try it out.

Comment: Sounds good.  I needed that feature to set drat repos so that's when it got added ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I never found an answer but this issue was not reproduced using `RJSONIO` so I switched to that package. I did try reinstalling `littler`, `R`, and `jsonlite` but the problem remained.